# how to route forms in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

When I search for a product with search parameter, I want to redirect url /products/search/ or /products/id/search.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
               name: "products",
               url: "products/{id}/{search}/{page}",
               defaults: new { controller = "products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When I search for a product in searchbox url showing /products?search=parametername. But when clicking in menu item url showing /products/search.

Answer (score 0):

add [HttpGet("{id:int}")] to top of your method in controller.
like this:

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public virtual async Task<ApiResult<List<PostShortSelectDto>>> GetSimilar(CancellationToken cancellationToken, int id)
    {
        return await _postRepository.GetSimilar(cancellationToken, id);
    }
```

Now router is like this:
/Controller/GetSimilar/1

If use .net mvc , use this code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetSimilar/{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<ApiResult<List<PostShortSelectDto>>> GetSimilar(CancellationToken cancellationToken, int id)
    {
        return await _postRepository.GetSimilar(cancellationToken, id);
    }
```

Comment: showing "HttpGetAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" error

Comment: nothing has changed. url showing /products?search=parametername

Comment: @userhk I wrote example if you want pass id as int, if you want pass string parameter as search you should change MapRoute